# ARCore with additional object recognition

Tags: conv-neural-network, mesh, point-clouds, arcore, object-recognition

*I know, the object recognition feature is currently not supported by Google's ARCore.*

My simple goal: detect cups and show some coffee inside. (Best would be display it live on the phone)

1. Is there really no way to detect objects?
2. Do you know any additional computations approaches, which can recognize some objects via ARCore?
3. Train a CNN. Instead of training image + annotation, use the point cloud + annotation. Is this approach viable?
4. Any approach, to record the a video + point cloud and compute them on a backend?
5. Is Snapchat using ARCore?
6. Are they detecting the face and pose to put the virtual makeup on the mesh?
7. How is the mesh computed?

I don't expect answers to every question, just ideas.

Maybe, someone knows simular projects, interesting links or something to think about.

**Thanks in advance.**